# How to control Over Zoom level in MKMapView in iOS

Tags: ios, mkmapview, android-mapview

Please check the below Image. How to Avoid this type of zoom level in iPhone

**Now getting Result:**

[image]

**Expected Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way of telling if satellite images would be available at zoom level for given region. Better approach is to set your `MKMapView` to `MKMapTypeStandard` and give the user the option of switching to `MKMapTypeSatellite` in this case you will always have a map details to display on initial presentation of your `MKMapView` object

Answer (score 0):

You can set the zoom by using MKCoordinateRegion and setting its span latitude & longitude delta as:

```
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = {desired lat};
region.center.longitude = {desired lng};
region.span.latitudeDelta = 1;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 1;
region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
```

Vary the span.longitudeDelta and span.latitudeDelta to get the required zoom.